# How do you update map items via a block for Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to update my Google Map with a polygon after a completion block:

```
[self.apiClient getActivityByID:self.activityID completion:^(NSDictionary *activity) {
        self.currentPolyline.map = nil;

        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:@"encodedPolyline"];


        self.currentPolyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];

        self.currentPolyline.map = self.mapView;


    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for `GMSMapView`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_view) says:

> GMSMapView can only be read and modified from the main thread, similar
>   to all UIKit objects. Calling these methods from another thread will
>   result in an exception or undefined behavior.

This probably applies to all map classes and operations, not just `GMSMapView` specifically.

So, you probably need to dispatch back to the main thread to update your line, eg:

```
[self.apiClient getActivityByID:self.activityID completion:^(NSDictionary *activity) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.currentPolyline.map = nil;

        GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:@"encodedPolyline"];

        self.currentPolyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];

        self.currentPolyline.map = self.mapView;
    });        
}];
```

Comment: I've done `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{...}]` but it did not work. Also I'm returning it in a block that's being called by AFNetworking, which should put it on the main thread.

Comment: Never mind, it was something else that I did wrong. Thanks!